# Can I specify a different folder for each package in a conanfile?

Tags: c++, conan

I have a couple different packages, and would like to put each one in its own folder (within my include directory). Is there a way to do this easily using conan?

Comment: it's not clear your question. Do you want to package 2 different recipes in different packages? Could you be more clear?

Comment: If you mean to have always includes like ``#include <mypkg1/myheader.h>`` and ``#include <mypkg2/otherheader.h>``, you need to make sure that in the ``package()`` method of each package you do ``self.copy(..., dst="mypkg1")``. Need more detail of what you mean.

Comment: @drodri that is what I meant, thanks

Comment: Cool, I will post a complete answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Conan packages do not have a fixed layout. Typically they will put public headers, in a `include` folder. It is acknowledged in C++ that a good practice is to have a layout for headers in a way that they are included like:

```
# include <somelib/file.h>
# include <otherlib/otherfile.h>
# include <yetotherlib/header.h>
```

This reduces the possibility of file name collisions.

When Conan packages package in their `package()` method, you could do:

```
name = "mypkg"
version = "1.0"

def package(self):
    self.copy("*.h", src="mysrcfolder", dst="include/mypkg")
```

Because the default `includedir` is `include`, that is:

```
def package_info(self):
    # This is not necessary, this is the default
    self.cpp_info.includedirs = ["include"]
```

This will make necessary to include like `# include <mypkg/file.h>`

Comment: Well, depending how the source code is arranged, or the layout, it might not be necessary at all, because the origin folder would already be ``include/mypkg``. If not the case, it can be parameterized: ``self.copy(...., dst="include/%s" % self.name)``